# How to convert URL into HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want a HTML document of an URL

I have URL like `www.example.com` and I want the HTML block of the page of URL.
How can I achieve this in JavaScript
I read that Java has method like `IOUtils.toString` to do the same.
can somebody suggest me how to do this or what is the method in JavaScript as in Java?

Comment: So you want to make an AJAX request to the URL and read the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using @Augustine Madu's answer
I used axios to call url

```
        const res = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"text/html"
            },
        })
        console.log(res.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const res = await fetch("www.example.com", {
  headers:{
    "Content-Type":"text/html"
  }
});

const html = await res.text()
```

Comment: I am getting error that res.text is not a function

Comment: Your GET request has no content and therefore does not require a content-type header. You're also missing the URL scheme (`http://` or `https://`)